# Version Control as a Web Application

Tags: svn, web-applications, rest, version-control

Couldnt find a Version Control system that I could simply install as a web application on a shared hosting provider. I wish for a simple REST based web application in PHP/Ruby with a backend of MySQL (or something).

Simply use GET and PUT to check-in check-out files.

- http://myServer/Repository/Files
- http://myServer/Repository/Revisions
- http://myServer/Repository/Users

This may be all I would need.

Database Backend wise 4/5 tables

Users
Repositories
Folders
Files
FileVersions
Revisions

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a thing exists. At least not in a form that is installable on PHP or Ruby shared hosting. (I researched this at one point pretty well.)